# Rebalancing a Binary Tree Using Array Recursively (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to balance a binary tree recursively by adding the tree data into an array in order, balance that data/ nodes (to minimize height) then insert the now balanced data back into the tree in the correct order. I am stuck on how to correctly do this all recursively. Here is the code if you scroll down you will see rebalance along with the methods I made to attempt to balance this tree:

```
package adts;
import java.util.Stack;
import interfaces.*;
import nodes.BSTNode;


public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> 
             implements BSTInterface<T>
{
    protected BSTNode<T> root;   // reference to the root of this BST
    
    boolean found;   // used by remove
    
    // for traversals
    protected ArrayQueue<T> inOrderQ;
    protected ArrayQueue<T> preOrderQ;
    protected ArrayQueue<T> postOrderQ;
    protected BinarySearchTree left = null;
    protected BinarySearchTree right = null;
    protected T[] rebalanceArray;
    
    public BinarySearchTree() {
        root = null;
    }
    
    
    public void add (T element) {
        root = recAdd(element, root);
    }
    
    private BSTNode<T> recAdd(T element, BSTNode<T> tree) {
        if (tree == null) {
            tree = new BSTNode<T>(element);
        }
        else {
            if (element.compareTo(tree.getData()) <= 0) {
                tree.setLeft(recAdd(element, tree.getLeft()));  // add to left subtree
                
            }
            else {
                tree.setRight(recAdd(element, tree.getRight()));  // add to right subtree
            }
        }
        return tree;
    }
    
    
      public boolean remove (T element) {
          root = recRemove(element, root);
          return found;
      }
      
      private BSTNode<T> recRemove(T element, BSTNode<T> tree) {
          if (tree == null) {
              found = false;
          }
          else {
              if (element.compareTo(tree.getData()) < 0) {
                  tree.setLeft(recRemove(element, tree.getLeft()));
              }
              else {
                  if (element.compareTo(tree.getData()) > 0) {
                      tree.setRight(recRemove(element, tree.getRight()));
                  }
                  else {
                      tree = removeNode(tree);
                      found = true;
                  }
              }
          }
          return tree;
      }

      private BSTNode<T> removeNode(BSTNode<T> tree) {

          T payload;
          
          if (tree.getLeft() == null) {
              return tree.getRight();
          }
          else {
              if (tree.getRight() == null) {
                  return tree.getLeft();
              }
              else {
                  payload = getPredecessor(tree.getLeft());
                  tree.setData(payload);
                  tree.setLeft(recRemove(payload, tree.getLeft()));  
                  return tree;
              }
          }
      }

      private T getPredecessor(BSTNode<T> tree) {
          while (tree.getRight() != null) {
              tree = tree.getRight();
          }
          return tree.getData();
      }

      
      public int size() {
          return recSize(root);
      }

      private int recSize(BSTNode<T> tree) {
          if (tree == null) {
              return 0;
          }
          else {
              return recSize(tree.getLeft()) + recSize(tree.getRight()) + 1;
          }
      }


      // this implementation of a size operation demonstrates that
      // it is possible to visit all the nodes of the tree without recursion      
      public int size2() {
          int count = 0;
          if (root != null) {
              LLStack<BSTNode<T>> hold = new LLStack<BSTNode<T>>();
              BSTNode<T> currNode;
              hold.push(root);
              while (!hold.isEmpty()) {
                 currNode = hold.peek();
                 hold.pop();
                 count++;
                 if (currNode.getLeft() != null) {
                    hold.push(currNode.getLeft());
                 }
                 if (currNode.getRight() != null) {
                    hold.push(currNode.getRight());
                 }  
              }
          }
          return count;
      }

          
      public boolean isEmpty() {
          return (root == null);
      }

          
  public boolean contains (T element) {
    return recContains(element, root);
  }
      
  private boolean recContains(T element, BSTNode<T> tree) {
    if (tree == null) return false;
    else
        if (element.compareTo(tree.getData()) < 0)
            return recContains(element, tree.getLeft());  // search left subtree
        else
            if (element.compareTo(tree.getData()) > 0)
                return recContains(element, tree.getRight());  // search right subtree
            else
                return true;  // element is found!
  }

  
  public T get(T element) {
    return recGet(element, root);
  }

  private T recGet(T element, BSTNode<T> tree) {
      if (tree == null)
          return null;
      else
          if (element.compareTo(tree.getData()) < 0)
              return recGet(element, tree.getLeft());  // get from left subtree
          else
              if (element.compareTo(tree.getData()) > 0)
                  return recGet(element, tree.getRight());  // get from right subtree
              else
                  return tree.getData();  // element is found!
  }
  
  public void rebalance() {
      
      T[] rebalanceArray = (T[]) new Comparable[size()];
      
      // I want to return the newly constructed/ balanced tree here
  }
  
  
  private BinarySearchTree constructBST(T[] rebalanceArray , int high, int low) {
      if (low > high)
          return null;
      
      int mid = (low+high)/2;
      BinarySearchTree node = new BinarySearchTree();
      
      node.left = constructBST(rebalanceArray, low, mid - 1);
      node.right = constructBST(rebalanceArray, mid + 1, high);
      
      return node;
  }
  
  private void storeNodes(BSTNode<T> root, BinarySearchTree nodes) {
      if(root == null)
          return;
      
      storeNodes(root.getLeft(), nodes);
      nodes.add(root); //add function not working
      storeNodes(root.getRight(), nodes);
  }
 

  // populate inOrderQ with tree elements based on in-order traversal
  private void inOrder(BSTNode<T> tree) {
    if (tree != null) {
        inOrder(tree.getLeft());
        inOrderQ.enqueue(tree.getData());
        inOrder(tree.getRight());
    }
  }

  // populate preOrderQ with tree elements based on pre-order traversal
  private void preOrder(BSTNode<T> tree) {
      if (tree != null) {
          preOrderQ.enqueue(tree.getData());
          preOrder(tree.getLeft());
          preOrder(tree.getRight());
      }
  }

  // populate postOrderQ with tree elements based on post-order traversal
  private void postOrder(BSTNode<T> tree) {
      if (tree != null) {
          postOrder(tree.getLeft());
          postOrder(tree.getRight());
          postOrderQ.enqueue(tree.getData());
      }
  }

  public int reset(TraversalType orderType) {
  // returns current number of nodes in the tree
      
    int numNodes = size();
    
    switch (orderType) {
       case INORDER :
           inOrderQ = new ArrayQueue<T>(numNodes);
           inOrder(root);
           break;

       case PREORDER :
           preOrderQ = new ArrayQueue<T>(numNodes);
           preOrder(root);
           break;

       case POSTORDER :
           postOrderQ = new ArrayQueue<T>(numNodes);
           postOrder(root);
           break;
           
    }

    return numNodes;
  }

  public T getNext (TraversalType orderType) {
 
      switch (orderType) {
         case INORDER  : return inOrderQ.dequeue();
         case PREORDER : return preOrderQ.dequeue();
         case POSTORDER: return postOrderQ.dequeue();
                default: return null;  
      }
  }
  
}
```

Here is the rebalance specific code:

```
  public void rebalance() {

      T[] rebalanceArray = (T[]) new Comparable[size()];

      // I want to return the newly constructed/ balanced tree here
  }


  private BinarySearchTree constructBST(T[] rebalanceArray , int high, int low) {
      if (low > high)
          return null;

      int mid = (low+high)/2;
      BinarySearchTree node = new BinarySearchTree();

      node.left = constructBST(rebalanceArray, low, mid - 1);
      node.right = constructBST(rebalanceArray, mid + 1, high);

      return node;
  }

  private void storeNodes(BSTNode<T> root, BinarySearchTree nodes) {
      if(root == null)
          return;

      storeNodes(root.getLeft(), nodes);
      nodes.add(root); //add function not working
      storeNodes(root.getRight(), nodes);
  }
```

input/ test tree:

```
package apps;

import adts.BinarySearchTree;

public class TestRUn800 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BinarySearchTree<Integer> testTree1 = new BinarySearchTree<>();
        
        testTree1.add(1);
        testTree1.add(2);
        testTree1.add(3);
        testTree1.add(4);
        testTree1.add(5);
        testTree1.add(6);
        testTree1.add(7);
        
        System.out.println(testTree1.treeHeight() + " tree height");
        System.out.println(testTree1.reckonUnbalanced() + " reckonUnbalanced Value");
        System.out.print(testTree1.rebalance()); // rebalance statement
    }

}
```

I did a lot of searching around on the web and saw some solutions that had a method that built the tree and stored it's data before then returning it in the original (rebalance()) method. That is what I have here in storeNodes and buildBST but cannot get it running correctly without errors. The error I am running into for add is "**The method add(Comparable) in the type BinarySearchTree is not applicable for the arguments (BSTNode)**" (I also commented next to add in the code so one can see where it is). Also as seen in the tree I find tree height, the unbalanced height (reckonUnbalanced) then I want to rebalance it and get it's new height (I have not written that code in this example though just what I plan to do once I get the actual code working for rebalance).

Comment: `but cannot get it running correctly or without errors` - please be more specific - which errors are you getting (and for what input)? which incorrect output are you getting (and for what input)?

Comment: Sorry I shouldve been more specific when I said that. I am getting an error for add in storeNodes. I have not gotten any output/ test results yet because I don't have any return statement in rebalance(). Thank you.

Comment: Which error are you getting? Please edit your question to include the error, as well as the input tree.

Comment: I edited my questions with the things you asked for. Thank you.

Comment: Your code doesn't pass compilation. `nodes.add(root);` is not valid, since your `add` method accepts an element of the tree (`T`), not a `BSTNode<T>`.